# How to secure connections over the internet?

Tags: c#, ssl, https

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to put this, but since I normally code in C#, and my potential solution would involve using C# I figured this would be the best place to start.

I've been given a task at work to allow our customers the ability to transmit confidential record information from their office to our in-house, or possibly a new cloud-based, server.

I have been rather adamint that to transmit said data, a SSL certificate must be aquired by us through a third party. But I'm wondering if that really is true.

The more I researched SSL certificates the more I've come to realize that all they really are is one company vouching for another. The encryption (even on an expired certificate or on a self-signed certificate) works and the encryption is just as secure as one that isn't. Sure, the user is presented with nasty icons and red screens showing that "hey! this may not be safe!" But if the user doesn't visit a "https" prefixed website and only visits a "http" website, what would be wrong with encrypting data client-side, submitting it to our server, decrypting it server side and vice-versa?

Encryption is encryption right?

Or what if a WinForms app was created that did the same as above? Encrypt data, submit it to our servers and the servers decrypt it.

I just can't justify paying thousands of dollars a year to have Verisign, or whoever, issue us a certificate when 99% (I'm willing to bet) of the users on the internet don't even bother checking the validity of the certificate.

I obviously want to make sure everything IS secure, and I'm not downplaying the role of SSL certificates or keeping things secure, but I just fail to see the logic behind aquiring one, if the same type of encryption can be achieved in-house with better control and, if you ask me, better security.

Any thoughts or opinions?

Comment: Your question is off-topic because it's asking for opinions. It also reads much like a rant. FWIW you should check your pricing structure for certificates. A basic certificate for a single site can be had for less than US$10.

Comment: @MikeW: This isn't actually an opinionated question; see my answer.

Comment: @Slaks The words 'Any thoughts or opinions?' rather set the tone of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about MITM attacks, which require some form of authentication to prevent.

If you just use a self-signed certificate, an attacker can impersonate your server and send his own self-signed certificates, and your clients won't know anything is wrong.

If you just encrypt data in Javascript, an attacker can easily modify the Javascript to send him a copy of the plaintext first.

If you already have a secure channel to distribute the client (eg, WinForms) app, you can use certificate pinning and your own CA instead of paying for an SSL certificate.  However, this involves more work on your part (remember to handle revocations).

Also, in order to securely distribute the app in the first place, you'll still need SSL.  (or an attacker can rip out all of your crypto code before it runs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of data you are trying to send, but you could certainly avoid using a website altogether to send and receive data. The strategy could be something like:

Client:

```
WinForm (data entry) -> SFTP server
```

Server:

```
SFTP server -> Windows Service -> SQL Database
```

You would just have to setup the SFTP service and deploy your WinForm and Windows Service securely.